# C++: Why does inputting a "char" for an "int" variable cause recursion to go crazy?

Tags: c++, recursion, input, types

For practicing the effects of input and output in C++, I wrote a small piece of code. I would like to know why it behaves like it does.

```
//A Stupid Program
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x;
cout << "please enter a numero: "; cin >> x;
main();
}
```

Running the code asks the user "please enter a numero: _" and simply repeats when a number is entered. This can be any integer. Typical output looks like this:

```
Please enter a numero: 1
Please enter a numero: 1
Please enter a numero: 152
Please enter a numero: 2
etc...
```

However, If you enter anything other than an int, the recursive loop goes crazy and starts printing "please enter a numero: " without asking for input. It looks something like this:

```
please enter a numero: H please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: please enter a numero: etc...
```

Then the program stops working and returns -1073741571.

So here's what I'd like help with: Why doesn't the program wait for input when a non-int is entered, and why does it return -1073741571?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the record, this program isn't even valid, because you're not allowed to call `main`. Clang wouldn't compile it.

Comment: It is illegal in C++ to call `main` in your program and therefore your question can be simply answered by "undefined behavior".

Comment: I use Code::Blocks, which allowed calling `main`. I understood, even as I was writing the code, that calling `main` recursively is a terrible idea. This program is merely an artifact of my experimentation.

Comment: The number -1073741571 is better understood as [`0xC00000FD`](http://deusexmachina.uk/ntstatus.html#C00000FD), which is the Windows exception code `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW`.  That is, your program was killed by the operating system because it consumed all of the memory allocated to its call stack.  This is what one would expect to happen to a program that enters an infinite recursion, as yours does.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae Recursively calling `main` in C++ is only undefined behavior because of -- I am not making this up -- the kludge used by the original [Cfront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) to implement global constructors.  All modern C++ compilers treat it the same way a C compiler is required to, i.e. it's a normal recursive function call.  (They would have to go out of their way to behave otherwise.)

Comment: @SebastianRedl The copy of clang on this computer only issues a warning, and only with `-Wextra`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you're calling `main` aside (you could just extract everything to a separate function), the problem is that when you enter something that a stream can't parse, it enters an error state where it returns from every operation immediately without doing anything. You need to check for the error state and reset the stream to get out of this.

Answer (score 2):

Reason for Infinite loop:
`cin` goes into a failed state and that makes it ignore further calls to it, till the error flag and buffer are reset.
In order to avoid it do:

```
int x = 0;
    while(!(cin >> x)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
    cout << "You enterd: " << x << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
   while(1)
   {
      int x;
      cout << "please enter a numero: "; cin >> x;

      if (cin.fail())
      {
         cout << "Please enter integer value! " << endl;
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```